# Showing $\frac{d^3\underline{k}}{2\omega_{k}(2\pi)^3}$ is Lorentz invariant

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, integration, lorentz-symmetry

> Show $\frac{d^3\underline{k}}{2\omega_{k}(2\pi)^3}$ is Lorentz
>   invariant.
>
> *Hint: try to evaluate $\int dk_0\delta(k_0^2 - M^2)\theta(k_0)$ where $M^2 = \underline{k} + m^2$*

My attempt is as follows,

$$
I = \int d^4k \delta(k_0^2 - M^2)\theta(k_0)
= \int dk_0 \int d^3\vec{k}\ \delta(k_0^2 - (|k|^2 + m^2))\theta(k_0)\\
= \int dk_0 \int d^3\vec{k} \delta(k_0^2 - (|k|^2 + m^2))\theta(k_0)
$$

then using $M^2 = m^2 + |k|^2 = \omega_k^2$ and $\delta(a^2-b^2) = \frac{1}{2|\omega_k|}\delta(a-b) + \frac{1}{2|\omega_k|}\delta(a+b)$ we get

$$
I = \int dk_0 \int d^3\vec{k} \Big( \delta(k_0 - \omega_k) + \delta(k_0 + \omega_k) \Big) \frac{\theta(k_0)}{2\omega_k}
$$
using the property of the theta function, we get,
$$
I = \int_{0}^{\infty} dk_0 \int d^3\vec{k} \Big( \delta(k_0 - \omega_k) + \delta(k_0 + \omega_k) \Big) \frac{1}{2\omega_k}
$$
integrating over $dk_0$ and using the fact that $\theta(\omega_k) + \theta(-\omega_k) = 1$
$$
I = \int \frac{d^3\vec{k}}{2\omega_k(2\pi)^3} \Big( \theta(\omega_k) + \theta(-\omega_k) \Big)
= \int \frac{d^3\vec{k}}{2\omega_k(2\pi)^3}
$$
however, I still have an integral for $\int d^3\vec{k}$ I don't know how to loose this integral without loosing the $d^3\vec{k}$!

Comment: Is this better suited to mathematics ?

Comment: I think the context of Lorentz invariance makes it on topic here.